# An if formula for multiple cells in another sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet that has 2 sheets, Sheet 1 with info in cells A and B.
I need to add a little formula in sheet 2, to check if any of the cells in sheet 1 column A (numbers) is bigger than the Numbers in column B cells, and then if so, say Yes else NO.

So IF in sheet1 any of the cells in Column A is bigger than in Column B, Then...."YES"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This checks on a row by row basis.  If you want to know if ANY row in column A is bigger than in column B, that would be a bit different.

`=if(Sheet1!A1>Sheet1!B1,"Yes","No")`

Comment: Hi, Thanks
Yes so essentially I need to know if any cell in "A" whether its 1 or 100, is bigger than any cell in B

Comment: This is still kind of vague, honestly. This option will tell you if _any_ value in A is bigger than _any_ value in B: `=if(max(A:A)>min(B:B),"yes","no")`, e.g. A2 could be larger than B55.  If you want to know if any An is bigger than Bn that's a different matter.

Comment: The array formula in google sheets works differently than excel.  My suggestion is to add a column `C` in Sheet1 that compares the value of A:B on a row-by-row basis, like so: `=if(Sheet1!A1>Sheet1!B1,1,0)`  You could then put this formula in Sheet2: `=if(sum(Sheet1!C:C)>0,"Yes","No")`

Comment: Thanks, Following works: The array formula in google sheets works differently than excel. My suggestion is to add a column C in Sheet1 that compares the value of A:B on a row-by-row basis, like so: =if(Sheet1!A1>Sheet1!B1,1,0) You could then put this formula in Sheet2: =if(sum(Sheet1!C:C)>0,"Yes","No") – Avram Penner 44 mins ago

Comment: Glad I could help.